# Why do some pipelines have regular 90 degree deviations?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, chemical-engineering

On this satellite image, there are pipelines extending from a terminal at sea to an LNG (Liquid Natural Gas) storage facility.  Why do the pipelines, at regular intervals, deviated from a straight line?

Is it a simple way to prevent / dampen shock waves from passing through the liquids from one end to the other and damaging equipment on the other end?  Could you use baffles in the pipes instead?  Would baffles significantly increase drag whilst these deviations increase resistance only slightly (due to longer pipe and forcing fluid to change direction multiple times)?

[image: regular deviations of three 90 degree turns in LNG pipeline on Grain island]
https://www.google.com/maps/@51.4402401,0.6996781,959m/data=!3m1!1e3

Comment: Expansion loops......